# .NET MAUI: Passing objects from ObservableCollection to an "AddObject" page and back (MVVM)

Tags: mvvm, maui

My main page has an ObservableCollection (defined in a ViewModel) holding objects (defined in a Model) and I have other pages, one that shows details and one to add a new object. I use the MVVM CommunityToolkit.

I can pass one object from the collection to the details page:

```
[RelayCommand]
async Task GoToDetails(DailyScrum scrum)
{
    if (scrum is null)
        return;

    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(View.ScrumDetailsPage)}", true,
        new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"Scrum", scrum }
        });
}
```

However, I am not able to pass the whole collection to the "Add" page, add the new object and pass it back:

```
[RelayCommand]
async Task AddNewScrum(ObservableCollection<DailyScrum> scrums)
{
    if (scrums is null)
        return;

    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(View.AddScrumPage)}", true,
        new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"Scrums", scrums }
        });
}
```

How can I do this? Or is it a wrong attempt to pass around the collection? Can I write access the collection from another viewmodel?

Comment: do you need a reference to the collection in the Add page?  Why not just create the new object in that page and pass it back via navigation when the page closes?

Comment: It is really a conceptual question of how to build the data architecture. This is part of a student project where I rebuild a Swift project in MAUI for comparison. In Swift you create what they call a (single) source of truth that is passed to other views as bindings. I tried to do the same here, but maybe for .NET there are other suggested concepts to follow, but I didn't find clear statements about that...

Comment: I believe that passing data via query parameters is using pass-by-value instead of pass-by-reference.  If you want to pass-by-reference you can use traditional navigation instead of Shell navigation

Comment: If you need a single source of truth, why not create a repository or database with an interface and then use dependency injection to access the different elements? You could use the query parameters of Shell navigation to hand over the IDs or keys of the objects that you need to access. When multiple Pages/Views and ViewModels need to access the same data, then I think a central data source like a database should be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ObservableCollection's size is small, you can try to use the `Newtonsoft.Json` package to convert it to string and then pass it. Such as:

```
var jsonstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scrums);
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(View.AddScrumPage)}?param={jsonstring}");
```

And convert the string to ObservableCollection with the following code:

```
ObservableCollection<DailyScrum> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<DailyScrum>>(jsonstring);
```

If the collection's size is big, you can store the string in the Preferences. Such as:

```
var jsonstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scrums);
Preferences.Set("Data", jsonstring);
```

And get the data in the `AddScrumPage`:

```
bool hasKey = Preferences.ContainsKey("Data");
var content = Preferences.Get("Data", string.Empty);
ObservableCollection<DailyScrum> data = hasKey ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(content) : null;
```

**Update**

You can try to use the `Shell.Current.Navigation`, it has the same effect as the `Shell.Current.GoToAsync`, such as:

```
[RelayCommand]
async Task GoToDetails(DailyScrum scrum)
{
    if (scrum is null)
        return;

    await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new View.ScrumDetailsPage(scrums))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I already create a json string to persist the objects in txt files. Didn't think about passing these. Still, I'm curious on what's the "right" (officially suggested) way ...

Comment: Preferences are not made for large amounts of text, there's even a section in the official documentation about this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android#limitations

Comment: This is temporary data, when read the data completely can call the `Preferences.Clear()` to delete it. It needn't to use the file IO. @ewerspej

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT What is the difference / advantage in using Shell.Current.Navigation over Shell.Current.GoToAsync?

And: this does not address my initial question about passing a whole collection. Right now, by saving a txt file for every object I found a solution that does not require to pass the collection at all. Therefore I can accept the solution as it points out to use JSON ...

Comment: Using the Shell.Current.Navigation can call the page's construction method when you navigate. So you can add a construction method with a pameter type of the ObservableCollection<DailyScrum> scrums to pass the data. @Lilly

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Strange that I cannot find any documentation on that, its not even mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: The official document mostly talk about the shell navigation with the route, but the Shell.Current.Navigation is like the traditional navigation Jason mentioned. @Lilly

Comment: OK, I am new to .NET, so no traditions here ;) Thanks for all the help